# Analysing how well an image is represented?

Tags: image, image-processing, raster, information-theory

Is there some algorithm that I can use to analyse image representation accuracies? Do people such as compression algorithm designers have some sort of objective way of comparing two image representations?

Say I'm trying to display a circle as a raster image; the higher the resolution, the closer the image comes to a perfect circle. The representations clearly become more accurate as you go along.

[image: Low Quality Circle] ->
[image: Medium Quality Circle] ->
[image: High Quality Circle]

Now, how can I *measure* how close a particular representation of the circle is to the circle?
One method I came up with was to measure the area of the bits that didn't match between the high res and low res image (the XOR):

| [image: Low quality difference] | [image: Medium quality difference] |
| --- | --- |
| 4.12% | 1.15% |

But how would I apply this to a non-silhouette image such as a photo or an anti-aliased image?
[image: Big lake]
[image: Small Lake]

[image: AA]

Comment: you're asking about error metrics. mean squared error (MSE), root-mean-squared error (RMS), [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity), [VMAF](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Multi-Method_Assessment_Fusion), ... -- perhaps ask this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: error compared to what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust error of a distorted image compared to a reference image. obviously this situation has a reference image, either as a literal image or as a platonic ideal. -- are you okay?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: I believe that the OP wants to tell the accuracy out of thin air.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not thinking of mosaic images, which are easy to detect from the pattern of repeated values.

For a natural image, the question does not make sense. The image is as accurate as it can, performing area sampling (and in any case you have no ground truth).

This is your antialiased image:

[image]